# Resolve rational indefinite integral?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How can I resolve this indefinite integral?

$$ \int \left({8,387x+1 \over 9,41x+1} + \sin(9,326x + 1)\right) dx $$

I'm blocked here

$$ \int\left({{8387 \over 1000}x+1}\over{{941\over100}x+1} \right)dx + \int\left(\sin\left({9326\over1000}x+1\right) \right)dx $$

please anyone can help me? thanks

Comment: Replace those strange numbers with some friendly ones so you do not get distracted while doing and learning the substitution method. Then apply what you learned to the general case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said above, I also think you are getting distracted by the "strange" numbers.

Assume you have

$\displaystyle\int\dfrac{ax+1}{bx+1}dx+\displaystyle\int\sin(cx+1)dx$,

where $a,b,c$ are some constants, then you can write

$\displaystyle\int\dfrac{ax}{bx+1}dx+\displaystyle\int\dfrac{1}{bx+1}dx+\displaystyle\int\sin(cx+1)dx$,

now just proceed by rewriting the first term as $\dfrac{a}{b}-\dfrac{a/b}{bx+1}$, this is, now you have

$\displaystyle\int\left( \dfrac{a}{b}-\dfrac{a/b}{bx+1} \right)dx+\displaystyle\int\dfrac{1}{bx+1}dx+\displaystyle\int\sin(cx+1)dx$,

and now you are able to integrate everything by declaring new variables as already suggested: $u=bx+1$ and $v=cx+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Do a substitution $w = 9.41 \, x + 1$ for the first and $y = 9.236 \, x + 1$ for the second integral.

Comment: but how can i resolve the 8,387x+1?